# Electric field of half a wire

Tags: electrostatics

[image: Drawing]

I am trying to calculate the electric field of a half wire in polar coordinates. At $y=R$ is a wire going from $-\infty$ to $0$ with charge density $\rho$.

I want to calculate the electric field at $(0,0)$

$$
\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{0}^{-\infty} dx \; \frac{\rho}{r^2} \hat{r}
$$

My idea was to integrate over the angle $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Then I get $\vec{r} = \frac{R}{\cos \theta} \hat{\theta}$ and my integral is

$$
\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} d\theta \; \frac{\rho \cos^2 \theta}{R^2} \hat{\theta}
$$

How do I solve this integral? I don't know what to do with $\hat{\theta}$ and what the resulting direction of the field is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you *REALLY* have to place the origin in a random point in space? You see, obviously the electric fielf such a wire produces will have a cylindrical symmetry around the line the wire extends along. So you place the origin where the wire ends, align the $z$-axis with wire and then only have E as a function of $z$ and $\rho$

Comment: I mean, if you have to calculate the electric field of a wire in the *exact* configuration depicted above, with wire running at the distance $R$ from the origin, there is no point in using cylindical coordinated.

Comment: Calculate separately for the horizontal and vertical direction - adding an additional sin or cos term.then it should be easy to do the integrals followed by a vector sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try itegrating over $\theta$ for the two components of the field, along $x$ and $y$ axes. So the integral equals 
$$E_x\propto\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \cos^2\theta \sin\theta d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \frac12\sin{2\theta} \sin\theta d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \frac14(\cos\theta - \cos{3\theta}) d\theta$$
$$E_y\propto\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \cos^3\theta  d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  (\cos3\theta + \cos\theta\sin^2\theta )d\theta 
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  (\cos3\theta + \cos\theta\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2)d\theta
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  (\cos3\theta + \frac{\cos\theta}2 - \frac14\cos3\theta -\frac14cos\theta)d\theta
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  (\frac34\cos3\theta + \frac14\cos\theta)d\theta$$

Which, I believe, are not complicated.

UPD: yup, seems I really lost it — the first of these two can be solved much easier by substitute:

$$E_x\propto\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \cos^2\theta \sin\theta d\theta 
=-\int_{o}^{\pi/2}  \cos^2\theta d\cos\theta
=-\big[\frac13\cos^3\theta\big]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac13$$

Comment: I did not check your math carefully, but thanks for showing in more detail what I wrote hand-wavingly in my comment.

Comment: Er, it just took me so long to type it that you had already made a comment by the time I sent the answer :)

Comment: Yes - I figured that anyone who could write these integrals didn't actually _need_ my suggestion to do so. Good work. ;-). But why not do the first integral directly as $\frac13 cos^3\theta$ - since the $sin\theta$ is just begging for you to do that...

Comment: My bad. Didn't do much integration since university, so just assumed that I'll do them both in the same way, i.e. transforming them into a linear combination of functions that are very easy to integrate. I'll fix that